# How do I remove all participants in R that only occur with one single variable level and never with the second one?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, bigdata

I am analyzing an online community dataset with R. I'd really appreciate your help since I am stuck at one problem. Here is an outline:

**Dataset:** The username of every user is available. Every row represents the activity of one user in one single online community. Example a: row 1 shows that user 'blue' is a 'member' of online community x to which he has contributed one post so far. Example b: row 5 shows that user 'blue' is also 'owner' of online community y to which he has contributed 2 posts so far. See below!

**Question:** I want to remove all users from the dataset that are only active as either member or user - in any online community. I also want to remove them if they are active as members in several online communities. In other words, I want to remove the users 'orange', 'purple', 'black'and 'white'. Important: the dataset contains > 1Mio. rows. I am looking for an approach that takes this into account :) Thank you.

```
username role   # of posts

blue    member  1
blue    member  0
red     owner   6
red     owner   1
blue    owner   2
red     member  1
blue    owner   3
blue    member  2
blue    owner   1
blue    owner   0
red     member  8
green   owner   1
red     owner   2
red     member  3
green   member  4
yellow  owner   5
green   member  3
green   owner   4
yellow  owner   5
yellow  member  6
yellow  owner   8

*orange owner   1
orange  owner   2
purple  member  3
purple  member  4
black   owner   4
white   member  4*
```

Comment: I don't understand how `In other words, I want to remove the users 'orange', 'purple', 'black'and 'white'` relates to the other description of your problem. Also, it seems that there should be an additional column for the online community because that's not clear from your example.

Comment: To clarify, you're looking to remove usernames if they don't show up as *both* `owner` and `member`?

Comment: @Adam, in that case, why is `red` not removed, for example?

Comment: Because `red` shows up as both member and owner (rows 3, 6)

Comment: Adam is right. Red shows up as both member and owner. Only the users should be removed that show up as ONLY member or ONLY owner.

Comment: @docendodiscimus: Thanks for your reply. The users 'orange', 'purple', 'black' and 'white' all show up as either ONLY owner (e.g. 'orange') or ONLY member (e.g. 'owner'). That's why they should be removed.

Comment: @Julius, perhaps you want something like `dt[, flag := uniqueN(role) > 1L, by = username][(flag)]`

Comment: Or `dt[, .SD[uniqueN(role) > 1L], by = username]`

Answer (score 0):

I assuming that the assertion in my comment was correct.

Using the `data.table` package, because I'm in a fanboy mood. Note that converting to a data table will break any data frame syntax you have afterwards, so if you're trying to plug this into other code, you'll want to use `setDF(users2)` afterwards to convert it back.

```
library('data.table')
setDT(users)
users_to_remove <- users[, .N, .(username, role)][, .N, username][N == 1, username]
users2 <- users[!(username %in% users_to_remove)]
print(setdiff(users$username, users2$username))
```

The 3rd line might be a little hard to follow, because it's chaining 3 operations.

1. Count the number of observations for each combination of username/role.
2. Discard the number of observations each combination has and count the number of roles each username has.
3. Restrict to usernames that have only 1 role, and return a vector of the usernames